# Identifying / replacing some jacks and removing glue

Tags: pcb, connector

I am by nature a CS / IT guy, and I am trying to replace some connectors on a relatively nice speaker system (Altec Lansing VS4121), as well as remove the (what appears to be wood) glue from it, for easier maintenance in the future.

I've included some image I've taken of the board here, for you to get a better idea what I am working with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GhHt.jpg

My question(s): where can I locate replacement jacks for the connectors shown (stereo mini-jack, a component / RCA mono jack, and something which appears similar to, but is not, a S-video jack), and what solvent should I use on the glue if I do not wish to damage the board? I was thinking that isopropyl alcohol probably wouldn't do the job, then thought of white vinegar, but since my interactions with PCB components has been somewhat limited, I thought better to ask before attempting.

I am also thinking of increasing the cable lengths (not shown) for some of the interior stuff, as they are barely long enough to connect with the board.

Comment: are the jacks broken or just need contact cleaner? more likely they used a polymer or polyurethane adhesive.. try mechanical means, less toxic, razor knive and dremmel. I would not recommend it.

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure. Here's what I do know, and can rely on your judgement: one of the cables (unsure which) will intermittently lose sound when moved around (a light touch will provoke this behaviour). Since it's a few years old and the cables themselves are really, really thick, I favour that the connectors themselves are either dirty or corroded.

Comment: Try contact cleaner spray or WD40 and find the source of the  plug or jack issue.

Comment: Any special knowledge for gleaning the difference? I hate to say it, but the jacks are close enough that I cannot be sure that the vibration induced by moving one cable is not affecting another.

Comment: -apply static force on each plug, radial directions.. does it affect left, right or both.. inserted fully?

Comment: Which cleaner would you recommend? I'm looking at Amazon as the possible supplier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I agree with the guys above, try to mechanically remove the connectors.  First though flip the board over and take a good look at the solder and see if it's cracked.  That's pretty common after mechanical stress.  If it is cracked a quick re-solder could fix.

If you have an meter you could check to see if the pins are making connection.  You could stick a pin or something to get into the tiny connectors, or a cut old cable, and then check each pin to see if a connection is being made.

**Buy the parts**

I'd try digikey the smaller connectors are [3.5 mm mono jacks](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/barrel-audio/1442625?k=3.5%20mm%20jack)
The s-video looking one I think is called a [mini din](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/circular/1441934?k=minidin).

Hope that helps some.